# Array of values from object where order is determined by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
const markets= [
    "SWE",
    "FIN",
    "NZL",
]
```

and an object:

```
const entries = {
  "FIN": 1,
  "NZL": 100,
  "SWE": 10,
}
```

---

I want an array with the **expected output to be:**

```
const values = [
  10,
  1,
  100
]
```

So the order of the resulting array is determined by the first, "markets" array, taking the help of the object keys being the same as the markets values.

They can **not** be sorted by magnitude, alphabetically, or in any other such way.

Edit: The array and object can be assumed to contain the same set of entries, it's just the order of these entries that do not necessarily match.

Comment: Just loop over `markets` and push the according value from `entries` in a new array (-> `Array.prototype.map()`)

Comment: you do not say if the lists  of the arrays are always coroborated

Comment: @MisterJojo what do you mean "coroborated"? The entries will always be from the same set, it's just the order that will sometimes vary and I therefore have to make sure the order matches.

Comment: ok, in this case you have to specify it in your question.

Comment: @MisterJojo oh ok I will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do

```
let values = markets.map(m => entries[m]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const markets= [
    "SWE",
    "FIN",
    "NZL",
]

const entries = {
  "FIN": 1,
  "NZL": 100,
  "SWE": 10,
}

const values = markets.map(rec => entries[rec])

console.log(values)
```

Comment: Here order won't be maintained.

Comment: @Asutosh it will return values in the same order as `markets`. This is what OP wants to do.